# insertRowsBefore() Method causing error: cannot convert (range) to class

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to write a script in google spreadsheets that, will read a range from a defined cell, take its value and `Insert` as many rows as the range would indicate, and then copy and paste an specific range also given by a range value in a cell.

Apparently the copy and paste range value works, but the range value for the `insertRowsBefore` is unable to convert the range value, any idea why this happens? I get this error

> cannot convert (range) to class

here is how the scripts looks like:

```
function CopyActualvsWMS() {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ActualVsSystem");
  var value0 = sheet.getRange('T4');   
  var r1 = value0.getValue();    
  var insert =ss.getSheetByName("DataBase").insertRowBefore(r1);    
  var value1 = sheet.getRange('T3');    
  var cr1 = value1.getValue();    
  var source = ss.getRange(cr1);    
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange("DataBase!a2"), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from this line:

```
var insert =ss.getSheetByName("DataBase").insertRowBefore(r1);
```

You are putting a variable name `r1` into the parameter, but the parameter must be a number (integer), not a string or a range reference.  The variable `r1` doesn't evaluate to an integer.  It's probably a string.

[Google Documentation - insertRowBefore()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowBefore(Integer))